# Redirect to a diverent page after specific date

Tags: javascript

i got the feeling I'm missing a little trick to get this working
But at the moment the code is not redirection to the **newpage**

**update fix was adding the callFunc()**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callFunc() {
    var compareDate = new Date(2014, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var curDate = new Date();
    if (curDate.getTime() > compareDate.getTime()) {
       window.location.replace('/newpage');
    } else {
       return "";
    }
}
callFunc()
</script>
```

Comment: Which part of your document is the script located––the head or body? And what are you using to call the function?

Comment: i know it was something stupid i looked over... forgot to call "callFunc()"

Comment: Ha. I was going to say that you could add `onload="callFunc()"` to the `<body>` tag.